# How can I implement OAuth in a desktop app?

Tags: authentication, oauth

I would like to write an email client that would send and receive mail on the Linux desktop. This is to be a local app, like Thunderbird, or mutt, not an online service. I would like it to be able to work through GMail, which requires OAuth authentication. All documentation I have been able to find on that or other Google APIs assumes that the implementation will be running on a server, where it can store client_id and secret in a place not accessible to the user. My app will be installed and run locally, and will be open source, so there is no way to store these credentials in secret.

Google goes out of its way to emphasize that the API key, the OAuth client_id, and its secret must not be published. Because of this, a few other email clients that have implemented OAuth support require each user to create his own API key and OAuth credentials. For an average user, the process for doing this is too complicated, and there is no way I am going to make them do it.

So the question is this: how can OAuth be done from a desktop app without requiring users to create API keys and credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **implicit flow** instead of code flow. Implicit flow is designed for handling a client-side authentication, which is your case.
Note that the implicit flow returns immediately the tokens on callback without using the client secret, resulting in implicit flow being less secure overall.

You can find more informations here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow

Comment: Unfortunately, implicit flow appears to not return a refresh token and thus requires a short, continuous session. When the user turns off his computer for the night, as most people do, he'll have to authenticate again when he turns it back on. Being a daily annoyance, this is even worse than forcing him to create his own API keys.